# flutter_local_notifications: "PlatformException (PlatformException(INVALID_ICON, The resource could not be found))

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to add notifications to my app using the flutter_local_notifications plugin but AndroidInitializationSettings requires a drawable resource and throws this error when one is not provided:

```
    "PlatformException (PlatformException(INVALID_ICON, The resource  could not be found. Please make sure it has been added as a drawable resource to your Android head project., null))"
```

The problem is that I don't know where Android head project is located.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Add your icon to `[projectFolder]/android/app/src/main/res/drawable` (for example `app_icon.png`) and use that name here:

```
var initializationSettingsAndroid =
    new AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
```

Comment: just reminding: notification icon should be white on transparent color 24dp, you can easily create them with the built-in tool in Android Studio. Right-click on Res folder -> New -> Image Asset -> Notification Icon there you can select any svg or image from the gallery

Comment: thank you, it fixed my problem. If someone want to use the default app icon, you can use it like this: AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');

Answer (score 136):

Hope you have solved it with above answered method, but I have solved with another method by using existing app icon.

```
var initializationSettingsAndroid =
    new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
```

Comment: Make sure to look for the icon file name in `/android/app/src/main/res/`. In my case, it was `launcher_icon.png`, so I used `'@mipmap/launcher_icon'`

Comment: Note that the code to be updated is found in main.dart